# Ordering nested / second level Arrays with Prisma?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I am using Prisma & PostgreSQL. Here I grab some stuff:

```
await prisma.items.findMany({
        where: { itemId: itemId },
        include: {
            modules: {
                include: {
                    lessons: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I do not need to order the `items` themselves, but I would like to order the `modules` & `lessons` that I get back. Both have an INT property (called: `number`) on which I could perform the ordering, but I do not know how to do this with prisma / postgresql, or even if it's possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `orderBy` operator for this.

Here's what the query would look like for your use-case:

```js
const data =  await prisma.items.findMany({
    where: {itemId: itemId},
    include: {
        modules: {
            orderBy: {
                number: 'asc'
            },
            include: {
                lessons: {
                    orderBy: {
                        number: 'asc'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The article on [filtering and sorting](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting) contains more information on this.